# Why divide the number of ways an event can occur by the total number of outcomes? and what does division actually mean in the context of probability?

Tags: probability-theory

This is the way that I have been taught to find the probability of something (in the simplest way), i.e. find the probability of getting 3 heads when you toss 4 coins, which is 4/16. Why would you divided them? Or rather, why would you divide the number of possible events to the number of all possible outcomes?

This also makes me wonder, what does division actually mean? In Arithmetic, its to distribute things in the most equal way possible among a number of things. What does this distribution have to do with probabilities of the sample space and the random variable?

Answers would be greatly appreciated!:))

Answer (score 0):

One way to construct probabilities is to count all types of a desired outcome (in your case, having a toss with 4 coins and get 3 Heads and 1 Tale) and devide it by all possible outcomes (every possible result of a toss of 4 coins). Important for this construction is, that all events are equally likely and countable.

When constructed like this, the probability, as you already mentioned, is 4/16.

You can think intuively about this, for example, if you have to decide between way A and way B. Only 1 of the two ways leads to your target, so your chance of getting the right way is 50%. Mathematically this means, you devided 1 desired way by the 2 possible ways: $1 \over 2$.

A random variable is a function from a sample space {all 16 outcomes} to a new sample space, usually real numbers. In this case, this distribution assigns to each event the same probability, which is $1 \over 16$. So the events are uniformly distributed ($1 \over n$).

But it could also happen that some events are more likely than others, then you would use some other function to map an event to a specific probability. What kind of function or distribution you choose, is up to you and depends on the problem you are trying to solve. One convenient way is to try to use a distribution that you already know like a Binomial distribution or Normal distribution.

Comment: Your introduction might benefit from the words "equally probable" perhaps as in: *One way to construct probabilities is to count all desired outcomes (in your case, having a toss with 4 coins and get 3 Heads and 1 Tail) and divide it by all equally probable possible outcomes (every possible result of a toss of 4 coins).*  Otherwise somebody might say there are only $5$ possible results (the varying number of heads) of which we desire $1$ and wrong conclude the probability was $\frac15$ since the ignore the point that these $5$ results are not equally probable